# Passing array to a method (Java)

Tags: java

I have a program that accepts a number that represents an array index and a
String to replace the array element corresponding to the index.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String names[]={"Alvin", "Einstein", "Ace", "Vino", "Vince"};

          for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++)
                 System.out.println(i + " - " + names[i]);

    replaceArrayElement(names);
}

   public static void replaceArrayElement(String name[]){

       int index = 0;
       String value = "";

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("\nEnter the index to be replaced:");
       index = scan.nextInt();

       if(index<name.length){

           System.out.print("Enter the new value:");
           value = scan.nextLine();

           name[index] = scan.nextLine(); 

           System.out.println("\nThe new elements of the array are");

           for(int j=0; j<name.length;j++)
               System.out.println(name[j]);
       } 
       else{     
            System.out.println("Error!");    
       }  
   }
```

What I need to do is to put the int index variable and String value variable inside the method replaceArrayElement as a parameters. But I don't know how to call a method with different data type parameters. Can somebody show me how?? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it's not clear where you'd get the values to pass in from, but here's how you would declare the method:

```
public static void replaceArrayElement(String[] name, int index, String value)
```

You'd call it with:

```
// Get the values from elsewhere, obviously
replaceArrayElement(array, 5, "fred");
```

Note that I've used `String[] name` instead of `String name[]` - while the latter syntax is *permitted*, it's strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

Declare replaceArrayElement as  follows -

```
public static void replaceArrayElement(int index, String value, String[] name)
```

and call it as -

```
replaceArrayElement(2, "Einstein2", names);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

String names[]={"Alvin", "Einstein", "Ace", "Vino", "Vince"};

          for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++)
                 System.out.println(i + " - " + names[i]);

    replaceArrayElement(3,"alpesh",names);
}

   public static void replaceArrayElement(int index, String replacename, String names[]){


       if(index<names.length){

           names[index] = replacename;

           System.out.println("\nThe new elements of the array are");

           for(int j=0; j<names.length;j++)
               System.out.println(names[j]);
       } 
       else{     
            System.out.println("Error!");    
       }  
   }
```

Comment: The new value of the array will be coming from the user input. Is it necessary to put another value for the name and index in the method when calling it?? i.e replaceArrayElement(3,"alpesh",names);

Comment: it is just example . you can change it what you want accordingly